# Dynamically writing js file

Tags: javascript, dynamic

Is it possible to create dynamic js file creation?
e.g. I am referring MyJs.js using  tag as usual, but source will be accompanied with a context value.

now what I expect, at server side, MyJs.js will be written according to the context value; just like a jsp page.

Is it possible?

Comment: will refer in the page like this : <script language="JavaScript"src="../MyJs.js?context=DATA_CAPTURE"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure. I guess you're using Java (given you mentioned jsp). Just map the request (MyJs.js) to your jsp (or whatever framework dispatcher you use) in web.xml, and then make sure to set the content-type of the response to text/javascript.

If you give more details then you might get a more detailed respones :)

Comment: Thanks,I forgot to think about Content-type.Basically I want to reduce response size. There are huge no. of JS functions which can be reused in different page. I am thinking a way out where I could load only required functions dynamically. context value will help me to filter out.

Comment: ok. good luck. It's worth ensuring the browser caches any 'static' javascript (using appropriate response headers). So, the response only needs to be delivered once ... It's often more efficient to serve one bigger js file once, than smaller js's on each page. (note that the browsers won't cache js when you use query strings)

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

just make sure your response header: Content-type set as: 'text/javascript';